# Javascript with JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using the Google Maps API to get a users location on the client side...I want to then send this to the server side to do some processing and populate a select box (with local addresses).

Whats the best way of doing this? Prefereably I would like to press a button and populate the box using ajax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to pass a Javascript value (your user location) to the bean with Ajax.

The location will be stored in the `<h:inputHidden>` field. The execute attribute of `<f:ajax>` specifies the value(s) that will be sent to the server to process.

```
<h:form id="formname">
    <h:inputHidden value="#{indexBean.value}" id="hvalue" />
    <h:commandButton value="action" onclick="getLocation();" action="#{indexBean.doSome}">
        <f:ajax execute="hvalue" render="output" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:outputText value="#{indexBean.output}" id="output" />
</h:form>
```

Before the Ajax request is sent the onclick attribute of the `<h:commandButton>` specifies the Javascript function to execute. Your Javascript function should set the value in your hidden field.

```
function getLocation() {        
    document.getElementById("formname:hvalue").value = "TEST";                       
}
```

The render attribue of `<f:ajax>` specifies what to update on the client side. In this case its an `<h:outputText>` in your case it will be your `<h:selectOneMenu>`.